# Not able to get img tag content

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` and I'm trying to get the content inside this two images tag:

```
<div style="padding-left: 27px;">
    <img src="http://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/578/img/events/appearance.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Presenze" title="Presenze"> 6 
    <img src="http://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/578/img/events/G.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Goal" title="Goal"> 0 
</div>
```

how you can see each img tag is not closed, I'm trying to get `6` and `0` using this code:

```
Convert.ToInt32(div.SelectSingleNode(".//img[0]").InnerText.Trim())
```

the `div` variable contains the html above. The problem's that I get `null` on this code: `(div.SelectSingleNode(".//img[0]")`.

Maybe 'cause the tag is not closed, infact I see only one item inside the `div` variable that contains all the img tags.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `null` primarily because XPath index starts from 1, *not* 0. The target text, however, is considered sibling of `img` instead of content/inner text.

That said, you can use `following-sibling::text()` and limit the result to 1, to get the nearest text node following the `img` element. For example to get the text after the first `img` element, you can use the following XPath :

```
//img[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

**Complete demo :**

```
var raw = @"<div style=""padding-left: 27px;"">
    <img src=""http://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/578/img/events/appearance.png"" width=""13"" height=""13"" alt=""Presenze"" title=""Presenze""> 6 
    <img src=""http://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/578/img/events/G.png"" width=""13"" height=""13"" alt=""Goal"" title=""Goal""> 0 
</div>";
var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(raw);
var query = "//img[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]";
var txt = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(query);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(txt.InnerText.Trim()));
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AQXbYQ)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
6
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this practice